# How to save and use file "safely" in express nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, file, security

I would like to save user file in my project, such as user's profile image(jpg) or user's grade information(xml).

Now,I know

- how to implement upload process in express
- how to use static file path in express (at "public" dir) (for "CSS", "JS", "page image")

But, If I upload user's file in public directory, client can access file in public directory just with url like "my_website/public/.../....xml". I think it is not good for security because everyone can access others' profile image, grade information, and so on.

So, my question is

- Is it okay to save user's sensitive information in public(static) directory?
- If not, is there any way to save file safely except database?
- In real websites, where they save user's sensitive information file? Is it in same directory with server files like main.js? or completely another server?

Comment: Just store it in another folder, somewhere, just not in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to save user's sensitive information in public(static) directory?

No, it is not OK.  That allows anyone access to private information.

> If not, is there any way to save file safely except database?

Yes, there are other ways.  For example, you could store a user's information in a directory just for that user and only allow users access to their data in their own directory.  This obviously required authentication with some sort of username and a credential/password.  You won't be using `express.static()` to access private information.  Instead, you will create a route for each type of resource, verify who the logged in user is and provide access to only the resources that belong to that logged in user.

> In real websites, where they save user's sensitive information file? Is it in same directory with server files like main.js? or completely another server?

There are lots of ways to implement user-specific storage, but it is highly unlikely that it is stored in the same directory as other server resources (like code files).  User-specific data would be stored somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!!
Then, How can I use file in html without static directory if I save user's file in another directory?
For example, how can I use <img src="USER's PROFILE IMAGE PATH"> in some html file, without static path?

Comment: @sms - Create a route for `/user/profileImage` or whatever you want the URL to be for the profile image and in that route's code, see what user is logged in and then use `res.sendFile()` to send the image for that specific user.  The same route will work for all users because the code in the route will get the appropriate image for that specific user.